# How to create a Vue project with tabs using Vue CLI

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, eslint, lint

When creating a Vue project using Vue CLI, all the files generated come with default 2-spaces indentation.

I'm trying to use tabs in my project. I tried many things but none worked. This is what I tried:

1. Changed the `'indent'` rule in `.eslintrc` to `['error', 'tabs']`.
2. Run `npm run lint --fix`. It identifies the errors but crashes and doesn't change spaces to tabs.
3. Run `./node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service lint --fix` and `npx vue-cli-service lint --fix`. Both of them identify the errors but they seem to completely ignore the `--fix` flag and they don't fix anything.
4. I did try to change them manually but the screen became almost red because of the changes.

My question:
How can I create a Vue project where **JS**, **Vue**, **CSS**, **HTML** use tabs instead of spaces?
Meaning that I don't want my JS to use tabs and HTML to use spaces, even HTML templates and CSS inside Vue components need to use tabs. **Everything** needs to use tabs. How can I achieve this?

Comment: to clarify, you want to use 4-spaces indentation when pressing tab?

Comment: @Evan no I want to use the tab character.